# Why $\langle k,n|\varphi(x)|0\rangle = e^{-ikx} \langle k,n|\varphi(0)|0\rangle$? (Srednicki's Quantum field theory)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, operators, correlation-functions

I'm reading Srednicki's Quantum field theory, p.94 and trying to understand some statement :

[image]
[image]

Why is the underlined statement true?

Q.1. What is the energy-momentum operator $P^{\mu}$?

Q.2. Why can we write $\varphi(x) = \operatorname{exp}(-iP^{\mu}x_{\mu})\varphi(0)\operatorname{exp}(+iP^{\mu}x_{\mu})$ ?

Q.3. Why $$\langle k,n | \varphi(x)|0\rangle = e^{-ikx} \langle k,n | \varphi(0)|0\rangle \tag{13.9}$$ is true?

Can anyone provides somewhat rigorous proof? Can anyone help?

Comment: Don't post screenshots, but use MathJax instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q.1 and Q.2 are basically definitions. You may refer to Section 2 of Srednicki.

At first, we have a unitary operator $T(x)$ corresponding to spatial translations ($x$ is understood as a 4-vector). Roughly, one may think that $T(x)$ translates everything within a quantum state by the vector $x$. Then, if we measure the expectation value of $\varphi(x)$ concerning the translated state, it would be equal to the expectation value of $\varphi(0)$ of the untranslated state. Therefore, $T^\dagger(x)\varphi(x)T(x)=\varphi(0)$.

Now, by definition, we clearly have $T(x)T(y)=T(x+y)$. So the set of all translations actually form a Lie group, and we may take its corresponding Lie algebra, whose generators are the momentum operators $P^\mu$. Hence $T(x^\mu)=\exp(-iP^\mu x_\mu)$. This answers Q.1 and Q.2.

With Q.2 given, Q.3 is straightforward:
$$
\langle k,n|\varphi(x)|0\rangle=\langle k,n|\exp(−iP^\mu x_\mu)\varphi(0)\exp(+iP^\mu x_\mu)|0\rangle
$$
The momentum operator doesn't act on $|0\rangle$, while $k$ numbers the eigenvalue of the momentum operator. So $\exp(+iP^\mu x_\mu)|0\rangle=|0\rangle$ and $\langle k,n|\exp(−iP^\mu x_\mu)=\exp(−ik^\mu x_\mu)\langle k,n|$. This answers Q.3.

Comment: Thanks for kind explanation. And why $\langle k,n|\exp(−iP^\mu x_\mu)=\exp(−ik^\mu x_\mu)\langle k,n|$? Can you explain more in detail? (Perhaps, is there any relevant literature that I can refer to? It seems that it is related to some part of contents of quantum mechanics but..)  I think that I don't know something about action of exponentiated differential operator.

Comment: That's by definition. The notation $|k,n\rangle$ exactly tells you that this is the $n$-th state satisfying $P^\mu|k\rangle=k^\mu|k\rangle$.